# Red5 installed on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. But oflaDemo not works

Tags: red5

I have installed the red5 server on Ubuntu 12.04. I download Red5-0.9.1, run red5.sh, and the index page works. The demo SOSample ( BallControl.html ) is working too.

However, the demo oflaDemo failed. It seems that the Java Spring Framework is not installed? The log is as following:

```
[INFO] [Launcher:/oflaDemo] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4ab84c: defining beans [placeholderConfig,web.context,web.scope,web.handler,demoService.service,org.springframework.scripting.support.ScriptFactoryPostProcessor#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@37165f
Exception in thread "Launcher:/oflaDemo" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scripting.support.ScriptFactoryPostProcessor#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/red5-web.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:946)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:890)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:671)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:401)
    at org.red5.server.tomcat.TomcatLoader$1.run(TomcatLoader.java:594)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2416)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2726)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2004)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:64)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:938)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aopalliance.aop.Advice
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 16 more
```

Does anyone see this error before? I don't know which package should I install now. Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Actually I just have the same problem on  windows! It used to work before !!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you miss some jar files

Can you find two jar like: 'spring-aop-x.x.x.jar' and 'aopalliance-x.x.jar' in [red5 Server path]/lib or your app lib?

Or you can try to add 'RED5_HOME' to your environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Finally I ran the red5-1.0.0 and it works fine. I tried lots methods for Red5-0.9.1, all failed..